# Hibernate won't save UserType

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

I have an object (Person) that I'm trying to save to a database, using Hibernate. Person has a Hibernate UserType object. I am unable to save Person to the database and I think the issue is the UserType.

I have logged the Sql to see what is going on and I have noticed that the logger has skipped the UserType parameter. Is this because the value is not being sent to the database?

```
insert into person_detail (code, person_type, person_id, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

22.01.15 16:16:41 TRACE [main] >>    [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder]  binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - J1
22.01.15 16:16:41 TRACE [main] >>    [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder]  binding parameter [3] as [NUMERIC] - 99
22.01.15 16:16:41 TRACE [main] >>    [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder]  binding parameter [4] as [NUMERIC] - Joe

> <typedef name='PersonType' class='com.TypedefEnumUserTyp'>    <param
> name='enumClassNam'>com.PersonType</param> </typedef>

<subclass name="Person" discriminator-value="PERSON">
    <join table="person_detail">
        <key column="person_id" />
        <property name="person_type" column="person_type" type="PersonType/>
        <property name="code" column="code" />
        <property name="name" column="name" />
    </join>
</subclass> 

public class TypedefEnumUserType extends AbstractToStringUserType implements UserType, Serializable, ParameterizedType {


private Class enumClass;

  public void setParameterValues(Properties params) {

    this.enumClass = classForProp("enumClassName", params);
  }

  public final String toString(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (value instanceof Enum) {
      final Enum eValue = (Enum) value;
      return eValue.name();
    }
    else {
      final String valueClass = value.getClass().getName();
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error trying to convert value to String. Expected instance of Enum, but got " + valueClass);
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public final Object fromString(String cached) throws HibernateException {
    if (cached == null) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, cached);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
      throw new SerializationException(enumClass.getName() + " value in database is invalid: " + cached, iae);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my record has been saving. The unit test was deleting my record immediately after saving so I presumed it was not being saved. I have the test wrapped in a transaction to roll back after it ran. Silly me.